# "CA2000 Dispose objects before losing scope" on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, code-analysis

I have an CA2000 warning in Code Analysis. But I can't find out how to solve it or why it's a problem. This is the code that fails:

```
 IController controller = new ErrorController();
      controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

I have tried to solve it like so:

```
using (IController controller = new ErrorController())
      {
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
      }
```

But MVC gives me this error:

```
55  'System.Web.Mvc.IController': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
```

I could just suppress the error, but I'd like to know what is causing the error and solve the problem.

Comment: Is `ErrorController` an `IDisposable`?

Comment: ErrorController is an MVC Controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the interface, I would swap it out for `var`:

```
using (var controller = new ErrorController())
      {
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
      }
```

This will allow the type to be inferred as an `ErrorController`.

The `IDisposable` interface is attached to the `Controller` class.  But does not exist higher up the chain.  [Here is the docs for `Controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  So, in order to dispose, you need to call it on the class that implements `IDisposable`.  Therefore, `IController` [won't work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: If i do like you suggest. It gives me this error Error 55 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)' is inaccessible due to its protection leve

Comment: This is due to a different issue based on what you are trying to achieve.  I assume this code is routing, however `ControllerBase` and `Controller` have `Execute` method marked as `protected`.  Perhaps, this could be the basis for another question?

Answer (score 4):

Your `using` statement is up-casting the `ErrorController` to an `IController`, which presumably does not implement `IDisposable` (whereas `ErrorController` *does* implement `IDisposable` in addition to `IController`). Change to either:

```
using (var controller = new ErrorController())
```

Or:

```
using (ErrorController controller = new ErrorController())
```